# How to expose a service which only binds to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: docker

I have a binary which is coded to bind exclusively to `127.0.0.1:80`. I would like to dockerize it and make it available from the rest of the network (like my other containers which expose a port because their services are bound to `0.0.0.0`).

The obvious-but-not-docker-elegant solution is to embark a reverse proxy in the container, and [run both services simultaneously](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) with `supervisord`.

Is there a better solution, which would somehow bridge the IP of the container with `127.0.0.1` to avoid the overhead?

Note: I cannot use `--network="host"` because it will interfere with the host own processes binding to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Try running inside the docker as a first step before running your software:

```
route add [SOME_LOCAL_IP_EXPOSED_TO_THE_SUBNET_NETWORK] 127.0.0.1
```

The expected results that external world (in the local subnet) should be able to talk to 127.0.0.1 via SOME_LOCAL_IP_EXPOSED_TO_THE_SUBNET_NETWORK.

To achieve this you can now pass the `--network="host"` to the docker, so that SOME_LOCAL_IP_EXPOSED_TO_THE_SUBNET_NETWORK will be mapped to your HOST's local IP for easier networking.